# Probability that the second highest value is inferior to some proportion of the max value + constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

I have a sample of n iid draws from a distribution (lognormal in my case, but I would like to do it with a general distribution). I focus on the ordered statistics $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, ..., X_{(n)}$.

I would like to compute:
$Pr(X_{(n-1)} \leq \alpha X_{(n)} + \beta)$, where $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $\beta$ a constant ($>0$) (eventually skip the constant I just wanted to make it more general).

So far I have that this is worth:
$\int_0^{+\infty} Pr(\alpha x \leq X_{(n-1)} \leq x) \cdot Pr(X_{(n)} = x) dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0} Pr(x \leq X_{(n-1)} \leq \alpha x) \cdot Pr(X_{(n)} = x) dx$

(remark that we can focus on distributions with positive support for what I want to do, so eventually skip the second term).

I know the formulas for the density/cdf of order statistics taken independently ( cf these [notes](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta104.1/Lectures/Lec15.pdf)), so I can compute this via numerical integration.
But first, I am not sure this is correct, second, I would prefer a closed-form formula as I think there should be one.
Is there any way to derive one easily?

Comment: I don't particularly see why there should be an analytical (closed-form?) formula.  Can you explain your intuition on that?

Comment: I think there should be a closed form (at least for know distributions like normal, lognormal, etc.) since all the joint distributions are normally well defined so there should be something to do (given that the question is also not so complicated). But I might be wrong, that's why I'm asking (my objective is to avoid numerical integration as much as possible).
I edited the title (wanted to ask something specific but then thought it would be better to ask the general question).